# C# Linq query to return part of column value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, out-of-memory

I am getting an OutOfMemoryException and I believe it is because the database column that holds the data I want to extract from the database is too large.  Is there a way I can only retrieve the first X number of characters from a column?  IE, read the first X characters, write to file, read next X characters until end of column, while saving to a file?

This column holds XML data and I want to transfer the XML stored to a text file.

### Update

Answering questions posted below:

Here is the Linq query where the OutOfMemoryException is thrown:

```
                  var output = db.ReportOutputs
                      .Where(i => i.ReportOutputId == rptoId)

                      .Select(i => new
                      {
                          i.ReportRun.ReportRunId,
                          //i.ReportOutputXml.ToString().Substring(1, 100),
                          i.ReportOutputXml,
                      }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Addressing @bradbury9, the ReportOutputXml is where the XML is stored in the report run table.

Comment: Could you show peace of code when you are getting OutOfMemoryException ?

Comment: Getting an `OutOfMemoryException` suggests you're trying to read, say, a few Gb of data, which is unlikely to be a reason of a single long column. Any chance you could share your query and some rough order of magnitude of the volume of data you're trying to process?

Comment: Tagged `xml` but talks about columns. a [mcve] would be nice to get a proper idea of the problem.

Comment: The best way to avoid memory problems when working with huge files is using streams, you could read the stream and on the fly write the desired data without getting large amounts of data in memory

Comment: Have you tried to ask on https://outofmemory.com, here we can only solve `StackOverflowException` ? And joke aside, see [mcve]. Hint: exception stack frame is often helpful, OOM often occurs due to recursive calls, e.g. same property is accessed in property setter.

Comment: Is commented line making a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the ideas.

What seems to be the issue in the version of DB2 that I have been using.  I tried the query in my instance of Toad for DB2 and got the same error when double clicking on the data column in the dataset to return that particular column value.

It seems my copy of Toad for DB2 4.0.1.921 is a Freeware version.  I went on the Quest site and got a new copy of DB2 and did not notice I clicked on the FULL version, 30 day trial.  I do not get the OutOfMemoryException using the Toad for IBM DB2 7.0.7.106 (non-freeware version).

This OutOfMemoryException could be a DB2 issue between Freeware and the Full version or a difference between DB2 4 and DB2 7.  Or there could be a setting in Toad for DB2 4.0.1.921 that I am not finding.